# TypeScript(err:2532): object is possibly undefined dispite null/undefined check

Tags: typescript, discord, undefined

I've been writing a Discord-bot in TypeScript and I added a command that retrieves information from an airport. The only thing you have to provide is the ICAO code of the airport(4 character code that identifies the airport). Now: Obviously users might get the ICAO code wrong and maybe give invalid ones. So that's why I have a method that retrieves the airport object from a JSON-File and looks a bit like this(not an exact replica, but just so you get an idea of it):

```js
public getAirport(icao: string): Airport | undefined {
    return arrayOfAllAirports.find(ap => ap.icao === icao);
}
```

In my command file/class I use this method to obviously retrieve the airport with the given ICAO code. Then I check if its return value is undefined and if so, I `return *some error*` and that is that. And that looks kind of like this:

```js
let airportMgr = new AirportManager();
    
let airport = airportMgr.getAirport(icao);
if (airport === undefined) {
    return *invalid icao error*;
}

*blablabla*

let exampleString = `ICAO: ${airport.icao} | Name: ${airport.name}`;
                                    ^error here             ^error here
```

But in two files/classes in which I use the said method together with the said checks I get an error further down, that the object might be undefined. Now comes the even more confusing bit: A few lines lower. I access some property of 'airport' again and it doesn't say anything.

Now I know I could use `as Airport` when I retrieve the airport or reassign it etc, but I want a proper solution and not cheat typescript in stupid ways. Do any of you have an Idea on how to get hold of this issue?

*edit:*

here's the picture of where it worked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTZyJ.png

Comment: Could you post your `tsconfig.json`? I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: I can't reproduce it myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `let`, not `const`. `let` can be reassigned which means that every time there was a chance it might have been changed, its type will be broadened to its original type. Something like this:

```js
// I made it async to demonstrate something below, for your case it is not important
async function doStuff() {
  // Some icao code
  const icao = 'some icao';
  let airport: Airport | undefined = getAirport(icao);

  // Let's start by checking whether the airport is undefined
  if (airport === undefined) {
    return;
  }

  // And now let's break down all the scenarios that work
  // and then all the ones that don't
  //
  // The important concept here is called lexical scope,
  // an "environment" in which variables and constants are defined

  // 1. current lexical scope - the scope of this function
  //
  // This should work since the value of airport has just been checked
  // and has not had an opportunity to be changed
  airport.name;

  // 2. "child" lexical scope - scope created by a function defined within
  // the current lexical scope
  // 
  // This should not work since you might be calling this function
  // some later time, when the value of airport would have possibly changed
  function someHelperFunction() {
    airport.name;
  }

  // The same applies to promise resolution values
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    // This should not work
    airport.name
  });

  // It works with simple awaits
  const anything = await Promise.resolve('something');
  // This will work
  airport.name;

  // A TRICK (!!!)
  //
  // You can at this point create a const of type Airport (because now you are sure
  // it is an airport) and use that in your functions.
  //
  // Since it is defined as const, it cannot be changed 
  // and it will stay an airport like forever and ever
  const airportForSure: Airport = airport;
  function someOtherHelperFunction() {
    // WORKS!!!
    airportForSure.name;
  }

  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    // Yesss
    airportForSure.name
  });

  // Then when you change the value of airport, you need to check for undefined again
  airport = getAirport(icao);

  // This will not work
  airport.name;
}

type Airport {
  icao: string;
  name: string;
}

// Just a placeholder for a function
declare function getAirport(icao: string): Airport | undefined;
```

[Link to TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=75&pc=64#code/PTAEElQWwQwEwKagJYBdQwM4E8B2BjUVAe1ESmN01QCcZUlNioFUALZXAc1ACMEANsQDuAGlAAzYjVDZiAVxn4sSNCkyhcxdMigAHaahi5UAKCx5CE%20QVTJKZYgGVU8iRIAUASlABvU6CgIKBOzKrKpPjEiAGgUVQ6EaAAvKAA5EwsKBFpANyxAqwYyDQGNKgAXKAAgiVl6AA%20oDaIEpwIcCmgXKy1pYYeyBFe%20bHBADKsGaDUMOV82HFsCPgA1pw8wsvsCDI7xf3zyBotCG24HbHIEqAeMHWGKcmpp%20cdPv6BgTSsirj5gQAvqYxmBqrhOlphKBCqhprwfjBVo5hLgMAIBERljN8AhcHN7Bp2PRQMJpKtQRgIVi8ejMftKAgiWwSXBKGkzIEQJSACrY3T1YzoeK4vToZY-dRxGAYjowhAADyGMpxxD0CFElOMoAARHiAG4lSgsEw6lBorZDNigfUEmC8QoaYydeKzExOyWtdpwEFcsAARgAdHFFD8TPKlcpMZgourQABaGmquPEG7sY6SGz4OyUUG8jgaTBsBQCTpkmjIzCcXFJ20CeRIVMHeqgFkaABW8mofAQtPwyzWlz9VM6bc02lb8CpoDV9RsaEWJB7S2MPR9gXuh1QgfxLFGw4ATMGdf3kKWzYVIyqY2qkImb3H8IiGJ1eIsYJnbPY0V6LmW0BwuCUvs%20Chni6CXsq0axgglL5hmRYlpCE7lpW1ZIHI8jQMgXBsOg-DShiGxYhm1hfrmw6ZEgAj0LsRC6BqpLLGi%20x1g2M43JuLZkvIpaTvqSAGJgVYOos-arkOn7Zt%20MxhAAEoI6o0AAYlmOa4N4fixBuDzlDuMB7rEwL5owBlIDAeh6AIyBMkQpB6DQzDHEgPxMPW6k2jKDaYLEAAKjlQM5gaucQAgCd4gY7BpmnJAAfFpXxBGAfIIcWvHIegqHac2hj6SwRkjL6SUQJl5IaMIAEzAKhQYMI9yoD5gSuugxjYOm3BdDAdVqP5TmYAgwVMqF4UZGE7VcGkhXDil5VnpiWU6VueUIPuxXVKAPIAErgAAwgA0rcACEx1eHmw4AJoKNKaIkumGgGJwwrPuZcSUN2TaoNgcZ9C2Hj8MoXZIFCshXXMjCKLBw5qBm2pcYYPjOs0-VYiSnAg4oUnqZggZncVTjoSgOgaL%20cpYK9CTiGoyi4Fo%20FIOJ3Bylq1JqBVGIzEY743bpEHIKsSBSD8AkyIjCDC7EzU5eUynSE4ENVD9jypHD5QApjMlUQA8jsNAKQISmqeRGkfNlwQAOqa5te1OMdh3ZSrqAyzQcs-MtavGYEvWBf1g1ueFXiRcxHgxfFnxfME51MsJ9s807LsDbukOgIChUmRazHoyujO1l5jacTz4iYZovadEu-YrMigvNBCZzehgXD3EBi0tqkPSoIr5SDMMq3BDNpJzeOpUVrEDtu6Yxmfd9PMJdkMDEFU1A0BsauJwvtDL%20PILBAAUl2LWgFZMC4sWpZ0VXH5kdJuaIPgNGSpfHltx3qBd3Pa9L9wXgK9PTSvN6uRAA)

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. But why does it work in other places?

Comment: Hmmm can you show me those? As a link or in your question

Comment: I don't know why the let worked in on but not in the other files. The way the variable is used is always the same and it just doesn't make sense. The constant thing worked, so thanks for that.